# In my CSS, background size property is not working properly, even if i set after bg img?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the below code I have given a class to the section and have used that class in css sheet, but the background image is not covering the whole section, it only covers 25 % of the section. My image size is 3000 x 2000.

```css
.section-testimonials {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(img/back-customers.jpg);
  color: #fff;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-testimonials">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Our customers can't live without us</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row>">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <blockquote>
        Omnifood is just awesome! I just launched a startup which leaves me with no time for cooking, so Omnifood is a life-saver. Now that I got used to it, I couldn't live without my daily meals!
        <cite>
          <img src="https://techmadeplain.com/img/2014/3000x2000.png">Alberto Duncan
        </cite>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: try adding `position:absolute;` and `width:100%;`

Comment: set your image as 100% width

Answer (score 0):

```css
.section-testimonials {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(img/back-customers.jpg);
  color: #fff;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="section-testimonials">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Our customers can't live without us</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row>">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <blockquote>
        Omnifood is just awesome! I just launched a startup which leaves me with no time for cooking, so Omnifood is a life-saver. Now that I got used to it, I couldn't live without my daily meals!
        <cite>
          Alberto Duncan
        </cite>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. I hope it'll work

```css
.section-testimonials {
         background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(img/back-customers.jpg);
        color: #fff;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 100%;
        position: absolute;
      }
```

```html
<section class="section-testimonials">
      <div class="row">
          <h2>Our customers can't live without us</h2>
      </div>    
      <div class="row>">
          <div class="col span-1-of-3">
              <blockquote>
                  Omnifood is just awesome! I just launched a startup which leaves me with no time for cooking, so Omnifood is a life-saver. Now that I got used to it, I couldn't live without my daily meals!
                  <cite>
                      <img src="https://techmadeplain.com/img/2014/3000x2000.png">Alberto Duncan
                  </cite>
              </blockquote>
          </div>   
     </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Well..the position:absolute worked but i am note able to set the background attachment property, if I do so the image disappears.
Also under .section-testimonials, I have a child blockquote whose position property is set to relative and the blockquote's child's position property is set to absolute?can you please explain that property?

Comment: background image is not disappears, its goes under the main image. so use `background-position` to fix your background image.

Answer (score 0):

Just unset `background-attachment` property

```
.section-testimonials {
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(img/back-customers.jpg);
      color: #fff;
      background-attachment: unset;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove background-attachment property and give background the height

```css
.section-testimonials {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(https://cmkt-image-prd.global.ssl.fastly.net/0.1.0/ps/2071937/3000/2000/m1/fpnw/wm0/curved_tv_3-.jpg?1482926954&s=79713e1a30148fedde42d2396fe9fc8a);
  color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-testimonials">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Our customers can't live without us</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row>">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <blockquote>
        Omnifood is just awesome! I just launched a startup which leaves me with no time for cooking, so Omnifood is a life-saver. Now that I got used to it, I couldn't live without my daily meals!
        <cite>
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/23/23656.svg" style="width:30px">Alberto Duncan
        </cite>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how to do it.

Key parts, `background: ..... center;` that will set the image to start growing from the center of the container. Try removing center and you will see that the top left of the image is teh BG of the section.

```css
.section-testimonials {
      background: url(https://techmadeplain.com/img/2014/3000x2000.png) no-repeat center;
      color: #fff;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
    <section class="section-testimonials">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>Our customers can't live without us</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row>">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <blockquote>
            Omnifood is just awesome! I just launched a startup which leaves me with no time for cooking, so Omnifood is a life-saver. Now that I got used to it, I couldn't live without my daily meals!
            <cite>
             Alberto Duncan
            </cite>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

remove background-attachment property

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}
.section-testimonials {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/beautiful_scenery_mountains_lake_nature_93318_3000x2000.jpg);
    color: #fff;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-testimonials">
  <div class="row">
      <h2>Our customers can't live without us</h2>
  </div>    
  <div class="row>">
      <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <blockquote>
              Omnifood is just awesome! I just launched a startup which leaves me with no time for cooking, so Omnifood is a life-saver. Now that I got used to it, I couldn't live without my daily meals!
              <cite>
                  <img src="https://techmadeplain.com/img/2014/3000x2000.png">Alberto Duncan
              </cite>
          </blockquote>
      </div>   
 </div>
 </section>
```